# How to redirect an image changing the path using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am able to partially do this with the htaccess code below, but for some reason it's still adding some of the path before the image.

Here is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*jpg$|.*gif$|.*png$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !mysitee\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)\.(jpg|gif|png)$ http://mysitee.com/?attachment=$1.$2
```

Essentially I need to remove the whole path except only for the filename and affix the end of the filename to a new path.

For example, one of the many images I have is:

```
http://mysitee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/myimage.jpg
```

But when I use the code my new URL is this:

```
http://mysitee.com/?attachment=uploads/2015/10/myimage.jpg
```

I have many images, so obviously I can't just redirect each image separately.

How can I make this so it doesn't also add the path before the image? I want it to look like this:

```
http://mysitee.com/?attachment=myimage.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just grab the last segment in your URL:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*\.(jpg|gif|png))$ http://mysitee.com/?attachment=$1
```

Comment: that works perfectly. As it turns out, however, I also need to exclude the file extension (i.e. .jpg) from the new url as well. But I will accept this since it's correct and add that as another question.